# Controller not being accessed despite being specified

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onsen-ui

I have a very simple app that has a splitter (onsenui) menu that opens different templates from `index.html`.

In `index.js` I declare a controller that should be bound to one of the template pages in index.html. I can follow with the debugger and watch the controller code be accessed during the first time the page is loaded, I assume it is being called on initial assignment, but afterwards the method `advance()` is never called when the button that should call it is pressed.

The method is assigned to the button using the `ng-click` directive.

Everything else works, it is only the controller and `onclick` that is not.

**index.html :**

```
<template id="traditionalrosary.html">
    <div>
        <ons-page id="traditionalrosary" ng-controller="traditionalRosaryController">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/traditionalrosary.css">
            <body>
                <ons-toolbar>
                    <div class="left">
                        <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
                            <ons-icon icon="md-menu"></ons-icon>
                        </ons-toolbar-button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="center">
                        Logo
                    </div>
                </ons-toolbar>
                <ons-card style="width:25vw; height 50vh; margin: auto;">
                    <img id="logoImage" class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.jpg" style='height=33vh; width=33vw; object-fit: cover; margin: auto;'>
                </ons-card>
                <ons-card style='left:50vh; width:75vw; height 50vh; margin: auto; object-fit: contain;'>
                    <textarea class="textarea" ng-model="textstuff" ng-init="textstuff = 'Hello now'" style="display: block; width: 100%; height 50vh; object-fit: contain; margin: auto; " value="OK" ' rows="10" placeholder="Textarea"> 
                    </textarea>
                </ons-card>
                <ons-button modifier="large" ng=click="advance()">advance</ons-button>
            </body>
        </ons-page>
    </div>
</template>
```

**controllers.js:**

```
myApp.controller("traditionalRosaryController", function($scope) {

    $scope.textstuff="nom nom";

    $scope.advance=function()
    {
        $scope.textstuff="awesome";
    };
});
```

`index.js`

```
window.fn = {};

window.fn.open = function() {
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    menu.open();
};

window.fn.load = function(page) {
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    content.load(page)
        .then(menu.close.bind(menu));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your HTML

Change `ng=click="advance()"` to `ng-click="advance()"`

Note the dash rather than the equals sign.